# Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException tengo este error y no se que hacer

Tags: rstudio

Estoy trato de hacer la variable driver.

driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver",
"C:/WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home/jdbc/lib/ojdbc8.jar")

Comment: Hola, sería útil que indiques qué estabas tratando de conseguir y si llamaste algún paquete con `library()`.

Comment: Estoy trato de hacer la variable driver, para enlazar R con oracle developer